# How to redirect to a simple page?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I'm using Spring Security and I have a big problem.

After the user logs in and he closes the page, when he enters again in "mysite.com" he should be redirected to the "/dashboard" but instead he gets error 404, page not found.

The only way for him to log again is using either another browser or i rr the server.

What's wrong with my config?? It doesn't redirect to /dashboard if he is logged in already.

```
  @Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/settings", "/users", "/teams", "/docker-status", "/container-creation").hasAuthority("Administrator")
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin().permitAll()
                .loginPage("/login").permitAll()
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/dashboard")
                .failureUrl("/login?error")
                .successHandler(authenticationSuccessHandler)
            .and()
            .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/logout")
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/login")
                .logoutSuccessHandler(logoutSuccessHandler)
            .and()
            .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(accessDeniedHandler);
}
```

Comment: I'm not too experienced with the software in question, but do unauthenticated users see a 404 when going to that page? Maybe it's not a 404 issue, in fact it definitely isn't as the page does exist, it's likely that the cookies are not being set on the user's browser before they are redirected.

Answer (score 0):

**Form and Basic Login Options**

You might be wondering where the login form came from when you were prompted to log in, since we made no mention of any HTML files or JSPs. In fact, since we didn’t explicitly set a URL for the login page, Spring Security generates one automatically, based on the features that are enabled and using standard values for the URL which processes the submitted login, the default target URL the user will be sent to after logging in and so on. However, the namespace offers plenty of support to allow you to customize these options. For example, if you want to supply your own login page, you could use:

```
<http>
<intercept-url pattern="/login.jsp*" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"/>
<intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
<form-login login-page='/login.jsp'/>
</http>
```

Also note that we’ve added an extra *intercept-url* element to say that any requests for the login page should be available to anonymous users [3] and also the AuthenticatedVoter class for more details on how the value IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY is processed.]. Otherwise the request would be matched by the pattern /** and it wouldn’t be possible to access the login page itself! This is a common configuration error and will result in an infinite loop in the application. Spring Security will emit a warning in the log if your login page appears to be secured. It is also possible to have all requests matching a particular pattern bypass the security filter chain completely, by defining a separate http element for the pattern like this:

```
<http pattern="/css/**" security="none"/>
<http pattern="/login.jsp*" security="none"/>

<http use-expressions="false">
<intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
<form-login login-page='/login.jsp'/>
</http>
```

From Spring Security 3.1 it is now possible to use multiple http elements to define separate security filter chain configurations for different request patterns. If the pattern attribute is omitted from an http element, it matches all requests. Creating an unsecured pattern is a simple example of this syntax, where the pattern is mapped to an empty filter chain [4]. We’ll look at this new syntax in more detail in the chapter on the Security Filter Chain.

It’s important to realise that these unsecured requests will be completely oblivious to any Spring Security web-related configuration or additional attributes such as requires-channel, so you will not be able to access information on the current user or call secured methods during the request. Use access='IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY' as an alternative if you still want the security filter chain to be applied.

If you want to use basic authentication instead of form login, then change the configuration to

```
<http use-expressions="false">
<intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
<http-basic />
</http>
```

Basic authentication will then take precedence and will be used to prompt for a login when a user attempts to access a protected resource. Form login is still available in this configuration if you wish to use it, for example through a login form embedded in another web page.

**Setting a Default Post-Login Destination**

If a form login isn’t prompted by an attempt to access a protected resource, the *default-target-url* option comes into play. This is the URL the user will be taken to after successfully logging in, and defaults to "/". You can also configure things so that the user always ends up at this page (regardless of whether the login was "on-demand" or they explicitly chose to log in) by setting the always-use-default-target attribute to "true". This is useful if your application always requires that the user starts at a "home" page, for example:

```
<http pattern="/login.htm*" security="none"/>
<http use-expressions="false">
<intercept-url pattern='/**' access='ROLE_USER' />
<form-login login-page='/login.htm' default-target-url='/home.htm'
        always-use-default-target='true' />
</http>
```

For even more control over the destination, you can use the authentication-success-handler-ref attribute as an alternative to **default-target-url**. The referenced bean should be an instance of AuthenticationSuccessHandler. You’ll find more on this in the Core Filters chapter and also in the namespace appendix, as well as information on how to customize the flow when authentication fails.

[Spring Security Reference docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.0.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/)